# What is the working area when a navigation bar is displayed in an iPhone application?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

When the navigation bar is visible in an iPhone application, does the zero point of the screen coordinate system begin from below the navigation bar?

Is the height of the screen below that bar 460?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jdg.net/post/106465937/standard-iphone-element-sizes) you can see the standard control sizes. If you're using UINavigationViewController, each pushed subview will have its coordinate system starting from below the navigation bar and total height of 426 (460 minus navbar's height).

Comment: The standard nav bar is 44pixels tall, so the available space would be 416, not 426.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you have a Navigation Bar it's height is subtracted from the total height so you'll have 480px - 20px (height of the status bar) - 44px (height of the navigation bar) = 416px

This is not true however if you have a translucent Navigation Bar, if the bar is translucent the height is not subtracted from the total height and you'll have 480px - 20px (height of the status bar) = 460px with your content drawn also below the Navigation Bar.

EDIT: Check your autoresizing masks, here's from the docs:

*When creating the views for your view hierarchy, you should always set the autoresizing properties of your views. When a view controller is displayed on screen, its root view is typically resized to fit the available space, which can vary depending on the window’s current orientation and the presence of other interface elements such as the status bar. You can configure the autoresizing properties in Interface Builder using the inspector window or programmatically by modifying the autoresizesSubviews and autoresizingMask properties of each view. Setting these properties is also important if your view controller supports both portrait and landscape orientations. During an orientation change, the system uses these properties to reposition and resize the views automatically to match the new orientation.*

Comment: I think so too.But I have toolbar below of screen,and when I print toolbar frame.origin.y it's print 416 and frame.size.height is 44.Should not origin.y  be 372 (416 - 44)?

Comment: Check the autoresizing masks of your view, they should be: `self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;`